# Python type hint for int / array of ints

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a function of an integer and a numpy array. It accepts a single int and a 1D array, or alternatively it accepts an array of ints and a 2D array which are then broadcast, e.g.

```
def norm_matrix(l, cov):
    norm_cov = cov / (l*(l+1))
    return norm_cov
```

My question is how to write the type hints in this case. Does this work?

```
def norm_matrix(
    l: Union[int, np.ndarray],
    cov: np.ndarray
):
```

and is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your way is correct. It is the default way.

If you find it too cumbersome you can do use the bitwise operator `|` instead as mentioned in the [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) documentation:

`l: int | np.ndarray`

But generally in Python we frown upon mixing input types since it complicates things. But like all rules, this one has an exception: [multimethods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Python) - Here is an [article by Guido](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605) explaining how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution coul be improved by using `numpy.typing.NDarray`
From the typing module of numpy